# How to solve null value in MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, select

I want to show data separately from income and expense table in MySQL using same query for both things but it show me when show income title date then same show  expense title date. But I need to do if it find income table's 4th row and if find expense table's 2nd row, but it show me 4th row. Why?

```
SELECT  income.date, 
        IF(income.income_sourch IS NULL, 'N/A', income.income_sourch )as 'Income Title',
        income.amount as 'income',
        IF(expense.expense_sourche IS NULL, 'N/A', expense.expense_sourche)  as 'ExpenseTitle',
        expense.amount as 'Expense'
from expense  RIGHT JOIN income
     ON expense.date=income.date
where expense.date='30-Aug-2016'
```

[image]

Comment: i need when find data from income and expense then don't duplicate value.please help me

Comment: I read your question like 10 times and don't understand what you are asking. Can you add the result you want to get (in both cases, one time with 2, one time with 4 rows), though I don't think what you are asking is possible (if I guess it correctly).

Answer (score 2):

Why - because that's how joins work when you have only a date to join the 2 tables. To solve this you need to create a relationship in addition to the date bearing in mind that at any one time the number of records in income could be greater than, less than or equal to the number of records in expenses. If we generate a row number for each row in income and independently generate a row number for each row in expenses then we can join income and expenses on row number
for example

```
/*
CREATE TABLE INCOME (ID INT,DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(10),DT DATE,AMOUNT INT);
INSERT INTO INCOME VALUES
(1,'SALE','2016-08-30',100),
(2,'ROKY','2016-08-30',200),
(3,'KORIM','2016-08-30',300),
(4,'SALEVOUCHR','2016-08-30',400);
CREATE TABLE EXPENSES (ID INT,DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(10),DT DATE,AMOUNT INT);
TRUNCATE TABLE EXPENSES;
INSERT INTO EXPENSES VALUES
(1,'RENT','2016-08-30',100),
(2,'UTILITIES','2016-08-30',100);
/*
```

This code

```
SELECT S.DT,S.DESCRIPTION,S.AMOUNT, s.rn,T.DESCRIPTION,T.AMOUNT, t.rn1
FROM
(
SELECT I.DT,I.DESCRIPTION,I.AMOUNT,
            @RN:=@RN + 1 RN
FROM     (SELECT @RN:=0) RN,INCOME I
) S 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT E.DT,E.DESCRIPTION,E.AMOUNT,
            @RN1:=@RN1 + 1 RN1
FROM     (SELECT @RN1:=0) RN1, EXPENSES E
) T ON T.RN1 = S.RN AND T.DT = S.DT
WHERE S.DT IS NOT NULL
```

results in

```
+------------+-------------+--------+------+-------------+--------+------+
| DT         | DESCRIPTION | AMOUNT | rn   | DESCRIPTION | AMOUNT | rn1  |
+------------+-------------+--------+------+-------------+--------+------+
| 2016-08-30 | SALE        |    100 |    1 | RENT        |    100 |    1 |
| 2016-08-30 | ROKY        |    200 |    2 | UTILITIES   |    100 |    2 |
| 2016-08-30 | KORIM       |    300 |    3 | NULL        |   NULL | NULL |
| 2016-08-30 | SALEVOUCHR  |    400 |    4 | NULL        |   NULL | NULL |
+------------+-------------+--------+------+-------------+--------+------+
```

BUT this is UNSAFE because it assumes that there are always more income than expense items
for example if we add 3 more expense rows

```
TRUNCATE TABLE EXPENSES;
INSERT INTO EXPENSES VALUES
(1,'RENT','2016-08-30',100),
(2,'UTILITIES','2016-08-30',100),
(3,'RATES','2016-08-30',100),(4,'SALARY','2016-08-30',100),(5,'INSURANCE','2016-08-30',100);
```

then the last expense item is lost resulting in

```
+------------+-------------+--------+------+-------------+--------+------+
| DT         | DESCRIPTION | AMOUNT | rn   | DESCRIPTION | AMOUNT | rn1  |
+------------+-------------+--------+------+-------------+--------+------+
| 2016-08-30 | SALE        |    100 |    1 | RENT        |    100 |    1 |
| 2016-08-30 | ROKY        |    200 |    2 | UTILITIES   |    100 |    2 |
| 2016-08-30 | KORIM       |    300 |    3 | RENT        |    100 |    3 |
| 2016-08-30 | SALEVOUCHR  |    400 |    4 | UTILITIES   |    100 |    4 |
+------------+-------------+--------+------+-------------+--------+------+
```

To cope with this we can simulate a full join like so

```
SELECT S.*,T.*
FROM
(
SELECT I.DT,I.DESCRIPTION,I.AMOUNT,
            @RN:=@RN + 1 RN
FROM     (SELECT @RN:=0) RN,INCOME I
) S 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT E.DT,E.DESCRIPTION,E.AMOUNT,
            @RN1:=@RN1 + 1 RN1
FROM     (SELECT @RN1:=0) RN1, EXPENSES E
) T ON T.RN1 = S.RN AND T.DT = S.DT

UNION

SELECT S.*,T.*
FROM
(
SELECT I.DT,I.DESCRIPTION,I.AMOUNT,
            @RN3:=@RN3 + 1 RN3
FROM     (SELECT @RN3:=0) RN3,INCOME I
) S 
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT E.DT,E.DESCRIPTION,E.AMOUNT,
            @RN4:=@RN4 + 1 RN4
FROM     (SELECT @RN4:=0) RN4, EXPENSES E
) T ON T.RN4 = S.RN3 AND T.DT = S.DT
```

result

```
+------------+-------------+--------+------+------------+-------------+--------+------+
| DT         | DESCRIPTION | AMOUNT | RN   | DT         | DESCRIPTION | AMOUNT | RN1  |
+------------+-------------+--------+------+------------+-------------+--------+------+
| 2016-08-30 | SALE        |    100 |    1 | 2016-08-30 | RENT        |    100 |    1 |
| 2016-08-30 | ROKY        |    200 |    2 | 2016-08-30 | UTILITIES   |    100 |    2 |
| 2016-08-30 | KORIM       |    300 |    3 | 2016-08-30 | RATES       |    100 |    3 |
| 2016-08-30 | SALEVOUCHR  |    400 |    4 | 2016-08-30 | SALARY      |    100 |    4 |
| NULL       | NULL        |   NULL | NULL | 2016-08-30 | INSURANCE   |    100 |    5 |
+------------+-------------+--------+------+------------+-------------+--------+------+
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help.it's working. brother why don't work where clause.i need when i find data reference by Date.can i make view table?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment can you rephrase or give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add limits inside the query

> if expense table limit 2 
>   if other limit 4

See how to add limit to the query with if condition

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean exactly, but there is no command like that.